# How to make CMake's FindJava get 64 bit Java with a 32 bit Visual Studio generator

Tags: java, cmake, 64-bit, 32-bit

I apply CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2017 solution to build a 32-bit application on and for Windows 10. To create the build system I let CMake call some Java tools to generate some of the code to compile (applying Eclipse Modeling Framework). To find Java itself I apply the CMake finder module `FindJava` in a `find_package(Java)` call.

I've observed that `FindJava` automatically selects the 32-bit version of Java in this case although a 64-bit Java is also available. Note, when I call CMake to generate for `Visual Studio 2017 x64`, `FindJava` returns with 64-bit Java. So, the Java version seems to depend on the bitness of the generator in use.

My problem is, that the 32-bit Java sometimes cannot allocate enough heap memory to execute the code generation tools.

To avoid that, I would like to have `FindJava` always find the 64-bit Java independent of the Visual Studio generator bitness.

**How can I achieve that?**

I currently use CMake 3.14 but could update if it helps.

#### Edit

I forgot to mention that I implement the CMake build system to be used by many developers on their machines. So I'd prefer to not assume a fixed path to the 32-bit and 64-bit Java installations on the build machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing the code of `FindJava.cmake` showed that it is currently not possible to select the Java bitness manually as requested.

I've filed a change request for that: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/20306

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try setting the environment variable JAVA_HOME in your CMake. You would however need to enforce that the developers set up their environment accordingly.

```
if(NOT DEFINED ENV{JAVA_HOME_64}) 
    message(FATAL_ERROR "This build requires setting your JAVA_HOME_64 environment variable to your 64 bit version of Java.")
endif()

set(ENV{JAVA_HOME} "$ENV{JAVA_HOME_64}")
```

Setting the environment variable in your CMakeLists will not affect the environment variable outside of your project. According to the [FindJava Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindJava.html), this should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of that. But the problem is, that I implement the build system for many users (developers) and I'm not sure if their Java installations all have the same paths. So, to be on the safe side I would prefer a kind of ``find_package`` option which is system-independent. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: In this case, I think we are limited with the actual implementation of Java. As it will always refer, by default, to JAVA_HOME, the only way that I can think of would be to enforce having an environment variable named JAVA_HOME_64 set, and assigning `set(ENV{JAVA_HOME} "$ENV{JAVA_HOME_64}")` at the beginning of the file. You could also guard the CMake using `if(NOT DEFINED ENV{JAVA_HOME_64}) message(FATAL_ERROR "This build requires setting your JAVA_HOME_64 environment variable to your 64 bit version of Java.")`

Comment: Yes, maybe that could be a solution although I always try to avoid any extra step for the developers.